# laravel 5.2 | upload file - Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Tags: php, laravel-5

i tried to upload profile picture pict but i got error "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null"

this is my method :

```
  $data = $request->input('fotodosen');
    $photo = $request->file('fotodosen')->getClientOriginalName();
    $destination = base_path() . '/public/uploads';
    $request->file('fotodosen')->move($destination, $photo);
    $data['fotodosen'] = $photo;
    Dosen::create($data);
```

create :

```
 {!! Form::open(array('fotodosen'=>'create', 'method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true, 'url'=>'uploads')) !!}
             {!! Form::file('image') !!}
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i> Register
                            </button>
                             {!! Form::close() !!}
```

already edit method to :

```
 $photo = $request->file('fotodosen')->getClientOriginalName($photo);
```

still got that error. what am i missing?

**UPDATE :**

```
public function store(CreateDosenRequest $request)

{



    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
        'admin' => $request->input('admin'),
     ]);

      $dosen = Dosen::create([
        'iddosen' => $request->input('iddosen'),
        'nipy' => $request->input('nipy'),
        'namadosen' => $user->name,
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'alamatdosen' => $request->input('alamatdosen'),
        'notelpdosen' => $request->input('notelpdosen'),
        'tempatlahirdosen' => $request->input('tempatlahirdosen'),
        'tanggallahirdosen' => $request->input('tanggallahirdosen'),
        'agamadosen' => $request->input('agamadosen'),

    ]);
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $data = $request->input('image');
            $photo = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $destination = public_path() . '/uploads/';
            $request->file('image')->move($destination, $photo);
            $data['fotodosen'] = $photo;
            Dosen::create($data);
 }
```

Comment: `$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the file name as `image`  try to use `image` instead of `fotodosen`

```
$photo = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Full code

```
$data = $request->input('image');
$photo = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
$destination = base_path() . '/public/uploads';
$request->file('image')->move($destination, $photo);
```

You can check for the file like,

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    // your code here
}
```

From [Http Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests) and an article [file upload in laravel 5](http://tutsnare.com/upload-files-in-laravel/)

Comment: still got error Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Comment: Use `var_dump($request->file('image'))` to debug.

Comment: i success upload file to server .but it create another row with empty data,  except 'fotodosen' coloumn . please check my update code.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue so I solved it using html form attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Example

```
<form name="le_form" action="/ft" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

For more information see

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype

Answer (score 0):

For me, what I found out is that i did not included the `enctype'=>'multipart/form-data` on the form. When i did, it eventually solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just do this if you are uploading a file or have a file field inside your form

```
 {{  Form::open(array('url' => 'dashboard/new_job', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')) }}
```

### OR

```
<form  action="/ft" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```